# Convert Blu-ray movie to DVD quality

Tags: video, video-conversion, mp4, blu-ray

I have a 30GB .mp4 file (personal full HD movie) which I want to convert to a DVD quality (4.7GB) movie. What is the best way/tool to do that?

Comment: You might want to provide a few more details.

Comment: The first step use `MakeMKV`to get files you can convert.  At that point you can use any video converter you want that supports the MKV file format

Answer (score 3):

One of the best tools for transcoding is [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/), it's easy to use and well supported.  You can specify target bit rates and such to do this.

> HandBrake is a tool for converting video from nearly any format to a
>   selection of modern, widely supported codecs.
>
> Reasons you’ll love HandBrake:
>
> Convert video from nearly any format
>   Free and Open Source
>   Multi-Platform (Windows, Mac and Linux)

Comment: looks good, let me give it a try

Answer (score 1):

DVD, 'quality' or do you want to burn it to a DVD? do you want the DVD to play in DVD players, or only blueray players, or only on your PC. Because if you want ot make a DVD you need to use MPEG 2 video codec. If you use h.264 you can have the same 'quality' but a much smaller file.